# "Не()подходящая для тебя компания". НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"Сколько раз я тебе говорил, они — не()подходящая для тебя компания!" — тут "не" слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раздельно, так как есть пояснительные зависимые слова "для тебя". Без этих слов было бы слитно: *...Они - неподходящая [плохая] компания.*

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что здесь частица НЕ должна писаться слитно, так как "неподходящая" - это в данном контексте не причастие, а отглагольное прилагательное. "Неподходящая для тебя компания" - это не то же самое по структуре и смыслу, что "Не подходящая к столу девочка". В слове "неподходящая" утрачена глагольность, на первый план выдвигается качественный признак. Для отглагольных прилагательных наличие пояснительных слов не имеет такого же значения, как для причастия, поэтому НЕ пишется слитно

Comment: Поддерживаю Вашу точку зрения. Глагольность, свойственная причастиям, здесь почти утрачена.

Comment: Звучит убедительно. Вот интересно, рассматривают ли этот случай в школе? Момент не из простых.

Answer (score 1):

У слова *подходить*  - не одно значение. Помимо значения "приближаться" (как в примере "не подходящая к столу девочка"), есть переносное значение "оказываться годным, удобным, соответствующим кому-либо, чему-либо". Причастие образуется как от глагола в прямом значении, так и от глагола в переносном значении (как в вопросе) - не подходящая для тебя - та, которая тебе не подходит.  Поэтому вполне логично писать раздельно при наличии зависимого слова. Именно так бы я рассматривала и в школе (Впрочем, в школе разные дети и разные классы. Есть очень толковые, которым можно об этом говорить, особенно, если они на филфак собираются поступать). В тестовой части ЕГЭ переходные, неоднозначные  случаи  не рассматриваются.

Но, надо признать, что признак глагольности действительно утрачивается. Например, я не могу представить такое употребление "это была не подходившая тебе компания" (т.е. признак времени утрачивается.)Хотя "не подходившие тебе платья я отдала"  - вполне звучит нормально.

Answer (score 0):

**inna**, в школе такие случаи рассматриваются. Классический пример на наличие глагольности: рассеянные дети и рассеянные семена.

Comment: Хорошо, с наличием глагольности ясно. А в школьной теме "Написание НЕ с разными частями речи" есть такой пунктик: пишем слова с НЕ слитно, если причастие утрачивает глагольность и переходит в другую часть речи - прилагательное?

Answer (score 0):

"Сколько раз я тебе говорил, они — не()подходящая для тебя компания!"
Да, с одной стороны, "неподходящая" - это причастие, перешедшее в прилагательное. Но, с другой, наличие зависимого слова "не подходящая для тебя" даёт возможность рассматривать "не подходящая" как причастие. Кроме того, по семантике - это не только плохая, но и та компания, которая не подходит. Поэтому, я думаю, что данное слово с НЕ пишется раздельно